# Running a process in the background and get the terminal back

Tags: linux

I'm running ethr tool to send TCP Traffic to my device. The Ethr tools sends traffic per interface and i have written a python script to execute the ethr tool command for multiple interfaces. I chose to run to execute the command in the background so that i can interate through.

The problem that I face is, using ampsersand '&' I'm able to send the process to background but it requires to press Enter to be able to get back the prompt. is there a way to get the prompt without pressing enter?

The command that I use to run the tool is: `./ethr -s ip 73.3.224.11 -4 -port 10499 -no &`

I tried to redirect to a file but the problem is the file size grows and my VM Crashes. kindly suggest any alternate solution pls

Answer (score 0):

Redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`:

```
./ethr <arguments> > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

since you don't seem to care about the output anyway